# Oracle Apex - Delete member from collection

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1

Is it possible delete from apex collection where C003 = 31

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DELETE_MEMBERS procedure is what are you looking for. To find out more about it please check the official [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/DELETE_MEMBERS-Procedure.html#GUID-527C6A66-3658-4DF6-8439-21DA4A6796FB).

You can do something like:

```
APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_MEMBERS 
(
    p_collection_name => 'collection_name',
    p_attr_number     => 3,
    p_attr_value      => '31'
);
```

Or use the sequence ID.

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR c_temp IS
    SELECT
        seq_id
    FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS
    WHERE collection_name = 'collection_name'
        AND c003 = '31';

BEGIN
    FOR r_temp IN c_temp LOOP
        apex_collection.delete_member
        (
            p_collection_name => 'collection_name',
            p_seq => r_temp.seq_id
        );
    END LOOP;
END;
```